# How to change the name of the choices in selectInput to avoid using URLs as the choice?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard for a project that I am working on.  In this project, I am trying to integrate a few plots from tableau.public.com using `renderUI`.  I want the dashboard to use `selectInput` to select which tableau plot will be displayed.  I have changed the URLs below so they will not work if searched.

My current code is:

```
plot1<-"https://public.tableau.com/views/Sheet2?:showVizHome=no&:embed=true"
plot2<-"https://public.tableau.com/views/Sheet3?:showVizHome=no&:embed=true"

fluidPage(
  ##### Give a Title #####
  titlePanel("Tableau Visualizations"),

  ## Month Dropdown ##
  selectInput("URL", label = "Visualization:", 
              choices = c(plot1,plot2), selected = plot1))
```

And code for displaying the Tableau pages:

```
renderUI({
tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%; scorlling=yes", src=input$URL)
})
```

The code does what I want it to do, except for the the selectInput option.  I would like to have the choices in the drop-down menu refer to the actual plot name (`plot1`, `plot2`).  However, since they variable names, the actual drop-down menu has the url listed.  I cannot use the following because then it doesn't recognize the choices as variables anymore:

```
  ## Month Dropdown ##
  selectInput("URL", label = "Visualization:", 
              choices = c("plot1,"plot2"), selected = plot1))
```

Is there anyway I can have the names of the variables displayed, but not the url that they represent?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a vector containing the plot names and a named vector which contains the urls like this:

```r
plot_names <- c("Plot1", "Plot2")
## Month Dropdown ##  
# Use the plot names here
selectInput("plot_name", label = "Visualization:", 
            choices = plot_names, selected = plot_names[1]))
```

And then to display the urls:

```r
urls <- c(Plot1 = "url1", Plot2 = "url2") # vector to get the urls from the names
renderUI({
tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%; scorlling=yes", src=urls[input$plot_name])
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do.  Thank you very much!